# Use JS variable inside a JS variable with an SQL Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, variables

I'm making an HTML5 Game. Once the game is finished, I'm inserting a score row into my game db:

```
var insert_score = '<?php $db->query("INSERT INTO square_game 
VALUES('','$id','gi','hiu')") ?>';
```

How would I insert a JS variable into this query instead of "gi" and "hiu"? I want to insert two variables called `score` and `round`.

**NOTE: The SQL Query is working and the information is being inserted into the db.**

Comment: if I understood the problem and the situation, you just need to concatenate the variables. e.g `',' + score + ',' + round + ')") ?>';`

Comment: You can't fetch js variables in this way. You need to pass them to the server with ajax.

Comment: @AlexanderPopov The js variables are on the same page, I'm almost positive this is possible...

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes Would you mind posting your answer as an entire SQL Query and not a portion of it?

Comment: var insert_score =  `'<?php $db->query("INSERT INTO square_game 
VALUES(',' + score + ',' + round + ')") ?>'`;

Comment: @CødePlay I'm wondering how you are going to execute the php code?

Comment: `var insert_score = '<?php $db->query("INSERT INTO square_game VALUES('','$id'.',' + score +',' + round)") ?>';`

Comment: @AlexanderPopov The php code is executed directly from the js variable after the game is finished.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes Is this the code you meant? See comment above...

Comment: I thought you had something else executing that.. you said it was working.. well.. if not, you should use ajax.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes The code is working and the information is being inserted into the server. I just don't know how to insert a JS variable into the values sent to the server...

Comment: But your code always inserts "gi" and "hiu" strings to the database, right?

Comment: @AlexanderPopov The computer is only doing what it's been programmed to do. I want to change the strings of `gi` and `hiu` to JS variables. It doesn't *always* inser these strings, because I can change the code...

Comment: @AlexanderPopov How would you do this with AJAX?